# I want to purchase the Toshiba Satellite C55-A5281 Laptop but need to make sure Ubuntu will work

Tags: installation, dual-boot, toshiba-satellite

I have had really good luck installing Ubuntu on many different random desktops and laptops, and I have never had a problem. But this would be the first windows 8 machine that I have purchased, and I have heard that windows 8 makes it harder to install ubuntu next to it, it doesn't want to play nice or something. I also need to make sure that the machine can boot from a USB stick so I can even install ubuntu. Has anyone had any experiance with this particular laptop? or other windows 8 things to look out for?

I think this is an ok link to check it out.. 
http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/C50/C55-A5281

Basically I am hoping someone who knows a bit more about it than I, can verify that I will be able to install ubuntu on it... I cannot abide windows. lol.

Comment: I've installed at least a dozen different distros over the years and have never had a problem. Over the past 2 days, I've tried to install about 6 different distros on the Toshiba (including Ubuntu 15) and none have booted from the hard drive. I've had Secure Boot disabled and boot using UEFI the entire time. I'm starting to think it's impossible to install Linux on this laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the good reply from @user87317:

Before making a decision, I prepare a fully-updated Live USB with my favourite applications. I pop into the store and, with permission from the staff, boot the display model using my Live USB.

The laptop needs to successfully boot and pass various tests, e.g. camera, microphone, playing multimedia, wireless Internet, touch-screen, connect to my phone via USB and Bluetooth (if it has Bluetooth), and run my must-have applications. (Test this on your existing computer to iron out any problems before you get to the store.)

The staff member is usually keen to give authorisation, because he hasn't seen Ubuntu before, is curious as to how you can boot something other than Windows from a Windows computer, and knows that he's more likely to make a sale if he allows you to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can search forum threads (on here or ubuntuforums.org) and see what problems (if any) other users with the same computer have come across.

Alternatively, you can check the list of Ubuntu certified hardware [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) . There are not Toshiba laptops in the list, but they may still be compatible or  requiring minor tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

I have  toshiba tecra a10. I installed

- Ubuntu 16.04 lts and
- Lubuntu 16.10. Now I have installed
- Lubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver.

All the versions worked very well for me.